# Odd and Even Functions

Tags: functions

What are odd **and** even functions?

*An interpretation with an example will be appreciated.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:A\to\Bbb R$ be defined on a set $A\subset\Bbb R$ s.t $-a\in A\iff a\in A$ ($A$ is symmetric wrt. origin).

We have two conditions $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $f(-x)=f(x)$. So, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$.

Comment: So, is this the only case?

Comment: As you can see. You can trivially verify that $f\equiv 0$ is both even and odd. I have checked necessity.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Functions who are odd **and** even have to satisfy two properties
$$(even) \qquad f(x)=f(-x)$$
$$(odd) \qquad f(x)=-f(-x)$$

from which you can deduce that, for all $x$, $f(x)=-f(x)$ which, in most contexts, means that $f(x)=0$. (for example, if you are in the reals, $0$ is the only odd **and** even function)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I understand from this that the only case that a function is both odd and even is when $f(x)=0$?

Comment: No, when $f(x)=0$. $x$ is not an even function, because $x \neq -x$

Comment: sorry, it was a typo!

Comment: @Hamad If a function is both even and odd it must satisfy both of the above properties/equations sum those two equations and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

And *odd* function is a function $f$ satisfying

$$\forall x,\quad f(x)=-f(-x).$$

**Examples.**

- $f(x)=\sin(x)$

[image]

- $f(x)=x^3$

[image]

Remark: and odd function $f$ always satisfies $f(0)=0$, and it's graph have a central-symmetry with the origin.

And *even* function is a function $f$ satisfying

$$\forall x,\quad f(x)=f(-x).$$

**Examples.**

- $f(x)=\cos(x)$

[image]

- $f(x)=x^2$

[image]

Remark: the graph of an even function is symmetric to the line $x=0$.

---

*Edit.*

If the function is odd **and** even, you can deduce from what I have previously said about the symmetries of the graph that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

You can also deduce that from an algebraic point of view using $f(x)=-f(-x)=f(-x)$, so $f(-x)=0$ for all $x$, so $f(x)=0$ everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated, but I meant when the function is both odd **and** even.

Comment: @Hamad My mistake, I edited at the end, to provide an answer using the geometric properties of the graph of such a function.